# Is ThreadLocal allocated in TLAB?

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, thread-local

I suppose, that ThreadLocal variables are allocated in Thread Local allocation Buffer(s) or TLABs, am I right ?

I was not successful in finding any document stating what exactly makes some class stored in TLAB. If you know some, please post a link.

Comment: I think all of the answers are correct, I had to choose one that although.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I was not successfull to find any document stating what exactly makes some class stored in TLAB. If you know some, please post a link.

Actually, the explanation is right there in the blog post you lnked to:

> A Thread Local Allocation Buffer (TLAB) is a region of Eden that is used for allocation by a single thread.  It enables a thread to do object allocation using thread local top and limit pointers, which is faster than doing an atomic operation on a top pointer that is shared across threads.

Every thread allocates memory from its own chunk of Eden, the "Generation 0" part of the heap. Pretty much everything is stored in the TLAB for a period of time - quite possibly your `ThreadLocal`s, too - but they get moved away from there after a gen0 garbage collection. TLABs are there to make allocations faster, not to make the memory unaccessible from other threads. A more accessible description from the same blog you linked to is [A little thread privacy, please](http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/a_little_thread_privacy_please).

Answer (score 4):

No. Here how it is:
As of 1.4 each thread in Java has a field called `threadLocals` where the map is kept. Each threadLocal has an index to the structure, so it doesn't use hashCode(). Imagine an array and each ThreadLocal keep a slot index.

When the thread dies *and* there are no more references to it, the ThreadLocals are GC'd. Very simple idea.

You can implement your own ThreaLocal(s) by extending Thread and adding a field to hold the reference. Then cast the Thread to youw own class and take the data.

So it's not TLAB, it's still the heap like any other object.

---

Historically there were implementations w/ static WeakHashMap which were very slow to access the data.

Comment: How is it in java 1.5, 1.6 ?  I think lot of things changed there.

Comment: @binary_runner - nope no changes, the wording is 'as of' (or since). Actually at first I could not understand the TLAB remark, where the memory is allocated has absolutely no bearing w/ the further assignment to a thread local. ThreadLocal is just a very normal java object and has no magic whatsoever (except may the Inherited version which is copied)

Comment: Downvoted, because the answer is mostly irrelevant and seems to misunderstand what TLAB is. gustafc's answer is the actual answer.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov, the very first word ('no') is on point. The answer explains how ThreadLocals work. TLAB is just a small area in the young gen (exclusive to the current thread, hence allocation is just a pointer bump). gustaf'c answer is not entirely correct either - larger objects are never stored in the TLAB. Yet, it was never asked what exactly TLAB is.

Comment: Even "no" is misleading, because taking the question into account "no" means "ThreadLocals are not allocated in the TLABs", whereas it should be "ThreadLocals do not get any special treatment in that regard". Java fields and hashCodes are irrelevant here. "GCed when no references left" is irrelevant. "it's not TLAB, it's heap" is misleading as TLABs are a part of the heap. WeakHashMap is even more irrelevant. gustafc says "pretty much everything is stored in the TLAB for a period of time" - "pretty much everything" means "almost everything", so he's correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that TLAB is used for object allocation of all small to medium objects.  Your ThreadLocal won't be allocated any differently.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that this is up to the discretion of the JVM implementer.  They could put the data in TLABs if they wanted to, or in a global table keyed by the thread ID.  The Java Language Specification tends to be mute about these sorts of issues so that JVM authors can deploy Java on as many and as diverse platforms as possible.

Answer (score 1):

i think only the pointer to it is, while the data itself resides in some other memory area. see http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/the_real_thing and http://wikis.sun.com/display/MaxineVM/Threads#Threads-Threadlocalvariables